# KendoWindow can close when its first opened, but not when its open a second time

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have some weird issue going on and I been trying to fix it over the last couple hours and have looked for answers on this but the only thing I find is the opposite. I have a Kendo Window that will close on my button click the first time that it is opened, but when I reopen the window my button click won't close it down. Everywhere I have looked people have the opposite issue.
Here is my code for the window

```
function CustomerPopupEditor() {
    $("#showCustomerEdit").append("<div id='window'></div>");
    var myWindow = $("#window").kendoWindow({
        width: "80%",
        height: "47%",
        title: "Customer",
        content: "/Customer/CustomerEditor",
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        close: function (e) {
            $("#window").empty();
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");
    myWindow.center().open();
}
```

here is my kendo toolbar that opens the window

```
template: "<button type='button' onClick='CustomerPopupEditor()' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> &nbsp"
```

and here is my code that I use to close the window when I click save

```
function CloseTheWindow() {
    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").close();
}
```

So for the life of me, I do not understand why I can get it to close on the first time it gets opened and not the second time that its opened.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem, but it looks that I am missing something. Please, check this [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AcOqU) if it is possible to reproduce?

Comment: how do you use `CloseTheWindow()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$("#window").data("kendoWindow").destroy();` instead of `$("#window").empty();`
This way kendo widget is destroyd. Otherwise, you just clean only html element.

Refer to how [Destroy Widgets](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/destroy)

Comment: That did the trick and thanks for adding a link for destroying widjets.

Answer (score 1):

Despite of the name, the [close](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-close) function will actually hide the window but it will remain as a DOM element.  So basically, when you create the window a second time your code will add a second `"#window` element in the DOM and it will also initialize the first `#window` as a kendoWindow while it's already a kendo Window.

So basically, what you need to do is to call the destroy function instead of close:

```
function CloseTheWindow() {
    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
}
```